# Code/Script to recursively search S3 bucket to unzip (GZIP) and move specific file from ZIP to new location

Tags: file, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip, gzip

Hi I have an S3 bucket containing gzip files. Within each zip there is a single TSV file I want to move to a new folder or bucket (dont really mind which). The S3 bucket will be added to with new zip file each hour so this script needs to be something I can schedule or trigger. Happy to use CLI, Lambda or any other method! Pointers, links, help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the fudge way to do this is with local processing:

1. Connect to S3

   AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
           config.ServiceURL = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
           AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
               S3AccessKey,
               S3SecretKey,
               config
       );
2. Copy Down the Files you want to process

   S3DirectoryInfo dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketname, "jpbodenukproduction");
          dir.CopyToLocal(@"C:\S3Local");
3. Decompress the Gzip (containing the tar, containing the multiple files):

   string directorypath = @"C:\S3Local";
           DirectoryInfo directoryselected = new DirectoryInfo(directorypath);
           foreach (FileInfo FileToDecompress in directoryselected.GetFiles("*.gz"))
           {
               Decompress(FileToDecompress);
           }

   public static void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
       {
           using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
           {
               string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
               string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);

   ```
           using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
           {
               using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
               {
                   decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                   Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fileToDecompress.Name);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now deal with the tar file (using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib):

   foreach (FileInfo TarFile in directoryselected.GetFiles("*.tar"))
           {
               var stream = File.OpenRead(TarFile.FullName);
               var tarArchive = ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar.TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(stream);
               tb1.Text = "Processing:" + TarFile.Name;
               try
               {
                   tarArchive.ExtractContents(@"C:\S3Local\Trash\");
               }
               catch (Exception ziperror)
               {
                   tb1.Text = "Delay Error in TarUnzip:" + ziperror;
                   Thread.Sleep(10000);
               }
               finally
               {
                   tarArchive.Close();
                   stream.Close();

   ```
           }
   ```

Finally do what you want with the unzipped files, I simply extracted the single file I need, recompressed and moved back up to S3.

My plan is to next convert into Lambda and get this running on a schedule.